# Gerar vários arrays diferentes contendo números aleatórios

Tags: python, random

Estou desenvolvendo um programa e preciso gerar um array de 16 elementos, em que cada entrada é `0`, `1` ou `2`; e depois preciso verificar se esse array satisfaz certas condições. Para gerar este array, estou fazendo:

```
ni = np.array(np.random.randint(0,3))
for i in range(15):
    n1 = np.array(np.random.randint(0,3))
    ni = np.append(ni,n1)
```

O output é:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2])
```

O problema é que este método as vezes gera arrays repetidos, o que atrapalha um pouco a performance do meu problema. Existe algum jeito de garantir que sempre será gerados novos arrays? No caso o array do output não poderia mais ser gerado.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é um problema de algoritmo, e vejo diversas opções.

Para exemplificar, vou trabalhar com um array de 2 elementos:

1. se você pensar, esse array pode ser representado por um numero que será escrito na base 3, sendo assim, os possíveis valores (para 2 dígitos)
   0(00), 1(01), 2(02), 3(10), 4(11), 5(12), 6(20), 7(21), 8(22)

Sendo assim, voce pode gerar um número aleatório entre 0 e 8 (3<sup>n</sup> - 1) e converter ele para array.

Para facilitar, vamos falar de um array de 3 posições (numero entre 0 e 26):

```
number # número aleatório entre 0 e 26
array[2] = number % 3
number = number / 3
array[1] = number % 3
array[0] = number / 3
```

Assim, você pode manter o registro de arrays mantendo um registro do `numero` em um array de cache.

```
cache # array de 3^n posições inicializado com false em todas as posições

do
  number = random(0, 3^n)
while cache[number] # o numero tem que ser regerado ate se encontrar um que nunca foi usado

cache[number] = true

array = gerar_array_from_number(number)
```

2. Gerar um string a partir do array e usar ela para checar se o array já foi gerado novamente:

```
string = array.join("")
```

3. utilizar outra função para gerar um hash do array e checar se ele já foi gerado anteriormente

---

Outra opção é gerar vários números entre 0 e 3<sup>n</sup> - 1, e convertê-los para a base 3, obtendo assim o respectivo array:

```
import numpy as np
from random import sample

def gerar_array(x, base, size):
    digits = []
    while x:
        digits.insert(0, x % base)
        x //= base
    if len(digits) < size:
        digits = ([0] * (size - len(digits))) + digits
    return np.array(digits)

# números que podem estar no array estão entre 0 e n - 1
n = 3

# tamanho dos arrays
tamanho_arrays = 16
# gerar 20 arrays diferentes
quantidade = 20

for i in sample(range(n ** tamanho_arrays - 1), k=quantidade):
    print(gerar_array(i, n, tamanho_arrays))
```

`sample` garante que os números gerados não se repetem, assim nem precisaria de um cache para saber se são repetidos.

Comment: Gostei muito desta ideia e tomei a liberdade de adicionar um código em Python que a implementa. Claro que se não concordar, basta reverter a edição.

Answer (score 2):

No fundo você quer "gerar N coisas aleatórias sem repetir" (vários arrays diferentes), então uma alternativa é seguir esta ideia:

- gerar todas as possibilidades (supondo que a quantidade total é 'X')
- escolher N índices aleatórios entre zero e X, e pegar as possibilidades que estão nestes índices

Para o primeiro passo, você pode usar [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), e para o segundo passo, use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) para gerar os índices, e [`itertools.slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) para pegar o elemento que está naquele índice. Algo assim:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, islice
from random import sample

# números que podem estar no array
nums = range(0, 3)
# tamanho dos arrays
tamanho_arrays = 16
# gerar 20 arrays diferentes
quantidade = 20
# quantidade total de arrays possíveis
total_arrays_possiveis = len(nums) ** tamanho_arrays

# sample pega 20 índices aleatórios entre zero e o total de arrays possíveis
for indice in sample(range(total_arrays_possiveis), k=quantidade):
    # gera as possibilidades
    todos_possiveis = product(nums, repeat=tamanho_arrays)
    # pega somente a que está na posição do índice
    lista = next(islice(todos_possiveis, indice, indice + 1))
    array = np.array(lista) # gera o np.array
    print(array)
```

Usei `itertools` porque seria bem custoso gerar todas as possibilidades e mantê-las em memória. No seu caso específico, há três valores possíveis (os números 0, 1 e 2), em um array com 16 elementos, então o total de possibilidades é 3<sup>16</sup> (ou seja, 43.046.721 de possibilidades - mais de quarenta e três milhões de arrays possíveis).

Usando `itertools`, os elementos só são obtidos quando necessário, economizando memória (e tempo também, pois gerar tudo demoraria muito).

Com `sample` eu garanto que não haverá índices repetidos, e assim garanto que o array a ser obtido nunca será igual aos que já foram pegos anteriormente.

---

Guardar os arrays já obtidos em uma lista e ir vendo se os novos já existem nesta lista (como sugerido na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/511308/112052)) também é uma opção, porém pode não escalar bem se a quantidade de arrays a serem gerados for muito grande. Por exemplo, se você quiser gerar 10 mil arrays diferentes, vai chegar uma hora que a lista terá, por exemplo, 9 mil arrays. Aí você terá que percorrer esses 9 mil pra ver se é repetido. Depois, percorre 9001, depois 9002, etc. É um algoritmo bem ineficiente (também chamado jocosamente de [*Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/)) - claro que para valores pequenos a diferença será ínfima, mas lembre-se que ["para valores pequenos, tudo é rápido"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/everything-is-fast-for-small-n/).

---

E vale lembrar que `itertools.product` gera todos os arrays possíveis (inclusive aqueles em que todos os números são iguais). Mas isso não é um "bug", já que com `randint` isso também pode acontecer (só tem uma chance menor, mas sendo "aleatório", não é impossível).

Comment: O último parágrafo me fez lembrar [dessa tirinha](https://www.americanscientist.org/sites/americanscientist.org/files/20144141249210337-2014-05TechnologueFp170.jpg).

Comment: @RafaelTavares Tem [essa](https://xkcd.com/221/) também  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode usar uma lista auxiliar? Caso possível é bem fácil: Crie essa lista e, após gerar o array de números aleatórios faça uma verificação, se a sequência for única é inserida no seu array, senão, gera uma nova sequência.

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
lista = []
ni = np.array(np.random.randint(0,3))
for i in range(15):
    n1 = np.array(np.random.randint(0,3))
    ni = np.append(ni,n1)
if lista já contém o valor gerado:
   gera uma nova sequência aleatória
else:
   salva o valor gerado
```

A verificação pode ser de maneiras variadas, então você pode escolher a melhor para o seu caso.